# Understanding the definition of an Interface

Tags: numerical-methods, definition

Im starting to learn about modeling of moving interfaces and am feeling daft about the basic definition itself:

Given an $n$ dimensional space $\Omega$ an interface $\Gamma$ is a co-dimension 1 object that splits the domain into  two distinct regions.

Ok so if $\Omega$ is a 2d domain, $\Gamma$ is a 1 dimensional object, i.e. a line that splits the domain.

The problem I have is with the motivating example, a circle in a 2d domain. Isn't a circle a 2d object, so it shouldn't count as an interface since its not codim 1? Or is it because we can parameterize the circle with just 1 degree of freedom that makes it 'count'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you get the idea that a circle is a 2D object (or what exactly you mean by that).  There are various notions of dimension, but usually if one can parametrize something by a function $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, one would see it as an $m$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$; alternatively, if a locus is defined by a set of $m$ equations in $n$ real variables, it can be seen as $n-m$ dimensional.  A circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is of course defined by one equation as in $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=b\}$.  There are other more sophisticated notions of dimension.

Comment: I was thinking of dimension in the grade school sense as in something varying in different directions. 1d varies along a line, 2d objects like triangles quads and circles have 'stuff' varying in two directions, and similarly for 3d. Viewing the dimension in the ways you describe answers my question by showing me that a constraining equation reduces the dimension of th object.